# Composer error al actualizar symfony

Tags: php, doctrine, composer, symfony

Estoy intentando actualizar symfony de la version 2.3 a una más avanzada, mi intención era sobre una 3.0 pero no hay manera.

Leyendo en los foros he actualizado el composer.json a una  "minimum-stability": "dev" pero aún así, siempre me da algún error de dependencia. También decir que no se para que sirven muchas de ellas, que yo sepa solo uso php, symfony y doctrine
Dejo aquí mi composer.json

```
   "require": {
    "php": ">=5.3.3",
    "symfony/symfony": ">3.0",
    "doctrine/orm": ">=2.2.3",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": ">1.6",
    "twig/extensions": ">1.0",
    "symfony/assetic-bundle": ">2.8",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": ">2.3",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": ">2.3",
    "sensio/distribution-bundle": ">2.3",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": ">2.3",
    "sensio/generator-bundle": ">2.3",
    "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": ">2.0"
},
"scripts": {
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile"
    ]
},
"config": {
    "bin-dir": "bin"
},
"minimum-stability": "dev",
"extra": {
    "symfony-app-dir": "app",
    "symfony-web-dir": "web",
    "incenteev-parameters": {
        "file": "app/config/parameters.yml"
    },
    "branch-alias": {
        "dev-master": "2.3-dev"
    }
}
```

}

Error de dependencia

> root@symfony2:/var/www/html/Symfony# composer update symfony/symfony
>   Loading composer repositories with package information Updating
>   dependencies (including require-dev) Your requirements could not be
>   resolved to an installable set of packages. Problem 1
>       - The requested package doctrine/doctrine-bundle (locked at v1.2.0, required as >1.6) is satisfiable by
>   doctrine/doctrine-bundle[v1.2.0] but these conflict with your
>   requirements or minimum-stability.   Problem 2
>       - The requested package twig/extensions (locked at v1.0.0, required as >1.0) is satisfiable by twig/extensions[v1.0.0] but these
>   conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.   Problem 3
>       - The requested package symfony/assetic-bundle (locked at v2.3.0, required as >2.8) is satisfiable by symfony/assetic-bundle[v2.3.0] but
>   these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.   Problem
>   4
>       - The requested package symfony/monolog-bundle (locked at v2.3.0, required as >2.3) is satisfiable by symfony/monolog-bundle[v2.3.0] but
>   these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.   Problem
>   5
>       - The requested package incenteev/composer-parameter-handler (locked at v2.0.0, required as >2.0) is satisfiable by
>   incenteev/composer-parameter-handler[v2.0.0] but these conflict with
>   your requirements or minimum-stability.   Problem 6
>       - symfony/symfony dev-master requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (5.5.9) does not satisfy that requirement.
>       - symfony/symfony 4.0.x-dev requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (5.5.9) does not satisfy that requirement.
>       - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony 3.4.x-dev
>       - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony 3.3.x-dev

No  tengo mucha experiencia, solo se me ha ocurrido que puedo instalar en una virtual los mismos paquetes para luego llevarme el composer.json y que lo tome de referencia, así supuestamente no tendrá incompatibilidades.

### cualquier ayuda será bienvenida

Si pongo master me sale esto:

> Problem 1
>       - The requested package doctrine/doctrine-bundle (locked at v1.2.0, required as >1.6) is satisfiable by doctrine/doctrine-bundle[v1.2.0] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
>     Problem 2
>       - The requested package twig/extensions (locked at v1.0.0, required as >1.0) is satisfiable by twig/extensions[v1.0.0] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
>     Problem 3
>       - The requested package symfony/assetic-bundle (locked at v2.3.0, required as >2.8) is satisfiable by symfony/assetic-bundle[v2.3.0] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
>     Problem 4
>       - The requested package symfony/monolog-bundle (locked at v2.3.0, required as >2.3) is satisfiable by symfony/monolog-bundle[v2.3.0] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
>     Problem 5
>       - The requested package incenteev/composer-parameter-handler (locked at v2.0.0, required as >2.0) is satisfiable by incenteev/composer-parameter-handler[v2.0.0] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
>     Problem 6
>       - Installation request for symfony/symfony master -> satisfiable by symfony/symfony[dev-master].
>       - symfony/symfony dev-master requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (5.5.9) does not satisfy that requirement.

Comment: esta claro que te intenta instalar algunos componentes principales (symfony/symfony) a una version que requiere php7, y segun el debug tu tienes una 5.5.9. Te diria que probaras a cambiar el **>** de la linea **"symfony/symfony": ">3.0",** por un **=** para forzar la 3.0 (que te admitiria el php5.5.9). El resto pueden ser problemas por las versiones indicadas, prueba a ponerles **"master"** en lugar de la version.

Comment: cambia el error pero, a mi entender, viene a decir lo mismo. Lo dejo en el primer post

Answer (score 4):

Lo que sucede es que tratas de actualizar sólo la dependencia referente a symfony (cambiandola de 2.3 a 3.0), y esto genera un error porque symfony requiere otras librerías que no se están actualizando.

Por eso, para actualizar a symfony 3.0 debe cambiar la versión de todos los vendors que salen en el "require" de composer, una buena guía es fijarse en el composer.json del symfony standard-edition: https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/blob/3.0/composer.json

Comment: Concretamente si pone la versión 3.0 que es la que quiere y ve como está en ella el composer debería irle perfecto.

Answer (score 0):

La complejidad de la actualización de un proyecto en Symfony esta basado principalmente en la calidad del código de éste. No hace mucho subí la versión de un proyecto de la v2.8 a la v5.2 pero el mayor problema fue que la calidad del código era mala y esto me retraso casi el doble de lo planificado. Te dejo los pasos que seguí para que te sirvan de apoyo.

1. Lo primero es verificar el estado del código que este obsoleto *(Deprecated)*. Para ello instalamos PHPUnit bridge.

`composer require symfony/phpunit-bridge`

2. Luego de haber actualizado todas las alertas que te da el paso anterior entonces puedes actualizar a la versión LTS siguiente del Framework.

   ```
        "require": {
            "symfony/symfony": "3.0.*",
        },
    }
   ```
3. Luego ejecuta composer update para actualizar el kernel

`composer update symfony/symfony`

> Puede ser que en el proceso salten errores por dependencias que estan
> obsoletas, en este caso entonces ejecutamos
>
> `composer update symfony/symfony -with-dependencies`

4. Ahora debemos actualizar el resto de los paquetes del *composer.json*

`composer update`

### Bibliografía

[Actualiza a una version superior Symfony](https://symfony.com/doc/2.6/cookbook/upgrade/major_version.html)

[Actualizar Symfony de 2.8 a 3.4](https://www.shopsys.com/5-5-steps-to-migrate-from-symfony-2-8-lts-to-symfony-3-4-lts-in-real-prs-50c98eb0e9f6/)

Comment: Si bien este enlace puede responder a la pregunta, es mejor incluir las partes esenciales de la respuesta aquí y proporcionar el enlace como referencia.  Las respuestas que son únicamente un enlace pueden dejar de ser válidas si la página vinculada cambia. - [Desde revisión](/review/low-quality-posts/258150)

Comment: @PabloLozano gracias por la corrección, mejore mi respuesta, espero que sea útil.